# Каким образом распакавать bz2 архив С++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо распаковать архив `.bz2`, желательно без внешних зависимостей. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Поиск в гугле дал `zlib` и `libzip`, но их придется скачивать. Есть какие-либо способы сделать это ничего не скачивая?

С++/Qt

Comment: zlib и libzip работают с форматом ZIP. Вам нужен формат bzip2 - это совершенно другой формат сжатия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без внешних зависимостей в Qt это сделать нельзя. Библиотека предоставляет только функции:

```
qCompress()
qUncompress()
```

но они нормально с zip файлами и другими файлами не работают. Кстати, они на основе zlib. Просто используйте zlib или [quazip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quazip/files/quazip/0.7/quazip-0.7.zip/download) и все будет работать для всех архивов.

Апдейт: Конкретно с bz2 работает bzip2, еще boost конечно.

Comment: quazip работает с ZIP. Автор же явно хочет распаковать bzip2 - совершенно другой формат.

Comment: Главное, что в Qt нет ничего встроенного, так что библиотеку придется скачивать и подключать